# Changing Fields in Access won't show change in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: ms-access, visual-studio-2015

I have a database with 2 fields that I made in Access. I added a new Data Source in VS 2015 and then added the DataGridView. The two fields showed up fine. But when I add another field in Access, I don't see the change in VS on refreshing.
When creating the data source, I chose the option to make a copy and I added the field in the copy itself.

I haven't added any code to the program.

Comment: What did you 'refresh' ?